# Json result with out backslash

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I am getting my my json result like below.Here i am getting **Back Slashes** in my data.

**"[{\"Route No_\":\"1001\",\"Description\":\"Testing\",\"Duration\":120,\"KM Coverage\":100.00000000000000000000,\"Mileage\":20.50000000000000000000,\"Allowance\":150.55000000000000000000,\"Repair And Maintenance\":200.22000000000000000000}]"**

My code is

```
    public string GetJSONDataForRouteInfo()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HITSEDGE\HITSEDGE;Initial Catalog=CCIL1;User ID=dbassist;Password=assist@123"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select [Route No_],[Description],[Duration],[KM Coverage],[Mileage],[Allowance],[Repair And Maintenance] from dbo.[CRONUS International Ltd_$Route]", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();               
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }

                serializer.Serialize(rows);

                string resultjson = serializer.Serialize(rows).Replace(@"\", "");
                return resultjson;
            }
        }
    }
```

And my **interface** is

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetJSONDataForCustmerinfo")]
    string GetJSONDataForCustmerinfo();
```

Here i try to replace '\' with double codes '"'.Here i need to get my result like

**[{"Route No_":"1001","Description":"Testing","Duration":120,"KM Coverage":100.00000000000000000000,"Mileage":20.50000000000000000000,"Allowance":150.55000000000000000000,"Repair And Maintenance":200.22000000000000000000}]**

How to get the result like this.

I replaced my code like below but same result.

```
 public string GetJSONDataForRouteInfo()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HITSEDGE\HITSEDGE;Initial Catalog=CCIL1;User ID=dbassist;Password=assist@123"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select [Route No_] as Routeno,[Description],[Duration],[KM Coverage],[Mileage],[Allowance],[Repair And Maintenance] from dbo.[CRONUS International Ltd_$Route]", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);                
                string json = string.Empty; ;
                json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);


                string outputjson = json.Replace("\\", "");


                return outputjson;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it not just because you are printing a string so it adds the backslahes to make it valid. What is consuming the resulting json?

Comment: How did you determine that your string contains backslashes? Did you write it out to a file or check its value during debugging? The debugger will escape double quotes, newlines and other non-printable characters  so `xxx"xxx` will appear as `xxx\"xxx` in the Watch windows.

Comment: I try to print in browser by running the URL .

Comment: Additionally, JavascriptSerializer isn't a Json serializer and shouldn't be used as it's old, comparatively slow and has too many edge cases. Use Json.NET instead. That's what's used in ASP.NET MVC and Web API

Answer (score 0):

try in this way

```
public string GetJSONDataForRouteInfo()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HITSEDGE\HITSEDGE;Initial Catalog=CCIL1;User ID=dbassist;Password=assist@123"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select [Route No_] as Routeno,[Description],[Duration],[KM Coverage],[Mileage],[Allowance],[Repair And Maintenance] from dbo.[CRONUS International Ltd_$Route]", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);  
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                   row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                   foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                   {
                     row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                   }
                   ws.Add(row);
                 }
                  return serializer.Serialize(rows);                    
            }
        }
    }
```

if you can use [Json.NET](https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/135702) you can do the following

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: which solution did you try?

Comment: where are you seeing this Back Slashes?? Are you sure that they are only in debug view? try output it

Comment: I am consuming this method from browser.And display in browser window.And one more thing i tried you JsOn.net solution.

Comment: Was the output equal with Json.NET too?