# Replace \ with " symbol in C# using Replace Method

Tags: c#

I want to replace \ with " symbol using C# code.Here i am writing code for it.

```
string str=jsonstringdata.Replace("\"",""");
```

But it showing error obviously.

Comment: You're still working on this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27289491/json-result-with-out-backslash use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) - seriously you won't regret it!

Comment: Sorry mr wetson i am not getting the expected out put.

Comment: Can you please post you code so that i may get result please.

Answer (score 4):

Use either single-quoted characters, @verbatim strings, or properly escape the characters:

```
str.Replace('\\', '"')
str.Replace(@"\", @"""")
str.Replace("\\", "\"")
```

Explanations:

1. Single characters are delimited with single-quotes characters `'`. The same backslash-escape rules from literal strings apply to literal characters, except that you can specify a double-quote directly (i.e. `'"'` instead of `'\"'`).
2. Verbatim strings in C# do not have backslash escapes (i.e. backslashes are interpreted literally) making them useful for file-paths. Verbatim strings do allow you to escape double-quote characters by doubling them up, like in VB's strings, e.g. `@""""` is a string containing a single double-quote character, similarly `@"foo""bar"` is a string with a single double-quote between "foo" and "bar".
3. Otherwise, with normal strings, use backslash to escape any special characters and backslash itself.

Answer (score 3):

this should do it - need to escape the correct characters.

```
string str = jsonstringdata.Replace("\\","\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str= jsonstringdata.Replace("\\","\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Characters must be escaped correctly.  Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp) for some more knowledge on JavaScript strings and how to escape the correct characters.

`string result = yourString.Replace("\\","\"");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle escape sequences correctly. Use a \\ for finding \   and \" for replacing each \ with ". See the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx

```
string input = @"\a\\\\";
char replaceble = '\\';
char replacingChar = '\"';
var output = input.Replace(replaceble, replacingChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the slash and quote characters.

```
var jsonStringData = "{ Hello\\World }";

string str = jsonStringData.Replace("\\", "\"");

// output of str = { Hello"World }
```